# flutter check if data exists in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to check if user selected data matches with my firestore data.

```
onPressed: () async{
               await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Checker (
                 from: fromSel,
                 to: toSel,
               )));
              },
```

and in the second page i used

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection('Schedules')
                  .where('from', isEqualTo: from)
                  .where('to', isEqualTo: to)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                if (!snapshot.hasData)
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index){
                            DocumentSnapshot power = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                            print(power['from']);
                            print(power['to']);
                            return Container(
                              height: 200,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text(power['from']),
                                  Text(power['to'])
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                      );
              }),
```

so the problem i'm getting is it's not displaying the value when i use `.where('from', isEqualTo: from)` but it works when i use `.where('from', isEqualTo: 'Adama')`. and also works with `.where('from', isEqualTo: from)` when i instantiate `from` value manually like `String from = 'Adama'`

can you please tell me what the problem is?

and below is my firestore structure
[image: Firestore data structure]

below is the whole code for the checker (renamed to search)

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:demo/BookingPages/budget.dart';
import 'package:demo/Lists/trip.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  final from, to, seat, adult, child, infant;
  final DateTime arrive, depart;
  Search(
      {Key key, this.from, this.to, this.seat, this.arrive, this.depart, this.adult, this.infant, this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState(from: from, to: to, seat: seat, adult: adult, child: child, infant: infant, arrive: arrive, depart: depart);
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
 // Stream<QuerySnapshot> comparision;
  var from, to, seat, adult, child, infant;
  final DateTime arrive, depart;
  _SearchState(
      {Key key, this.from, this.to, this.seat, this.arrive, this.depart, this.adult, this.infant, this.child});



  Stream<QuerySnapshot> comparision(BuildContext context) async* {
    try{
      yield* Firestore.instance
          .collection('Schedules')
          .where('from', isEqualTo: from.toString())
          .where('to', isEqualTo: to.toString())
      // .where('dates', arrayContains: widget.depart.day)
          .snapshots();
    }catch(e){
    print(e);
    }
  }

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   // TODO: implement initState
  //   comparision = Firestore.instance
  //           .collection('Schedules')
  //           .where('from', isEqualTo: from)
  //           .where('to', isEqualTo: to)
  //           .snapshots();
  //
  //   super.initState();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('Schedules')
                      .where('from', isEqualTo: from)
                      .where('to', isEqualTo: to)
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                DocumentSnapshot power = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                                print(power['from']);
                                print(power['to']);
                                return Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(power['from']),
                                      Text(power['to'])
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                          );
                  }),
            )
            // Expanded(
            //   child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            //     stream: comparision,
            //     builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot) {
            //       if (!snapshot.hasData)
            //         return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            //       return ListView.builder(
            //           itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            //           itemBuilder: (context, index){
            //             DocumentSnapshot power = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            //             print(power['from']);
            //             print(power['to']);
            //             return Container(
            //               height: 200,
            //               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            //               child: Column(
            //                 children: [
            //                   Text(power['from']),
            //                   Text(power['to'])
            //                 ],
            //               ),
            //             );
            //           }
            //       );
            //     },
            //   ),
            // ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}

class TripCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TripCardState createState() => _TripCardState();
}

class _TripCardState extends State<TripCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

below is my first page code which includes the values

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'search.dart';

class Other extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OtherState createState() => _OtherState();
}

class _OtherState extends State<Other> {

  var from = [
    'Addis Ababa', 'Adama', 'Dire Dawa', 'Ali Sabieh', 'Djibouti'
  ];
  var fromSel = 'Addis Ababa';
  var to = [
    'Addis Ababa', 'Adama', 'Dire Dawa', 'Ali Sabieh', 'Djibouti'
  ];
  var toSel = 'Djibouti';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
        child: Container(
          //height: 203,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 15,),
              Container(
                //decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-19,
                      height: 60,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('From', style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.grey
                          ),),
                          SizedBox(height: 0,),
                          Expanded(
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
                                items: from.map((String value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Text(value, style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18
                                    ),),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                              isExpanded: true,
                              isDense: false,
                              elevation: 5,
                              hint: Text('From'),
                                value: fromSel,
                                onChanged: (String newValue){
                                  setState(() {
                                    this.fromSel = newValue;
                                  });
                            }),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(height: 50, child: VerticalDivider(color: Colors.grey)),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-19,
                      height: 60,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('To', style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: Colors.grey
                          ),),
                          SizedBox(height: 0,),
                          Expanded(
                            child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
                                items: to.map((String value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Text(value, style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18
                                    ),),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                isExpanded: true,
                                isDense: false,
                                elevation: 5,
                                hint: Text('to'),
                                value: toSel,
                                onChanged: (String newValue){
                                  setState(() {
                                    this.toSel = newValue;
                                  });
                                }),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
                child: MaterialButton(
                   onPressed: () async{
                     await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Search (
                       from: fromSel,
                       to: toSel,
                       depart: _startDate,
                       arrive: _endDate,
                       seat: _options[_selectedIndex],
                       adult: adultSel.toString(),
                       child: childSel.toString(),
                       infant: infantSel.toString(),
                  
                    )));
                     
                   },
                  minWidth: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width - 80,
                  height: 45,
                  shape:
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  splashColor: Colors.green,
                  child: Text(
                    "Search",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So, it seems this is not a Firebase-related issue, then. Please include the whole code for your `Checker` widget.

Comment: looks like the from variable is not exactly a string or at the point where it's used it's not a string. have you checked that?

Comment: @SrilalSachintha i tried it using `.where('from', isEqualTo: from.toString)`

Comment: @Riwen i added the checker page. although i renamed it to "Search" now. and in the code there are commented parts which shows what i tried.

Comment: Is it possible you are not actually passing a valid value to `Checker`? Where does `fromSel` come from? If you put a breakpoint there, does it have a valid `String` value?

Comment: @Riwen the `fromSel` is a value from a dropdown button. i'll post the first screen code